# Why were Reds considered more dangerous than oranges?

Tags: the-darkest-minds

It seems like an orange can be far more dangerous than a red since they can tear apart peoples minds:

> Clancy would have been so proud of me. The way I'd used those kids, twisting them, manipulating them, ripping into Rob's mind until it shattered.

Also, we know that if the orange is strong enough they just have to be close enough to a person to enter their mind:

> All I needed now was to channel the *want* I felt burning a hole in the center of my chest, and picture Rob's face, and the invisible hands peacefully unfurled, slithering under the seats that separated us like wisps of smoke. I had him; I dropped into his mind with the grace and steadiness of an anchor through water.

**But** we do know that people can fight the control of a orange:

> Vida made a noise like a small gasp, her face scrunching with the force of Clancy's intrusion. She shuddered, fighting it- I could see it in her eyes just before they went glassy under his mind's touch.

The final reason that leads me to believe that oranges are more powerful is that they can control groups of people at the same time:

> The boys around him began to nod in agreement, their faces strangely expressionless.

The things we know that makes the reds dangerous is that they have pyrokinetic abilities but it seems like if it came down to a fight an orange with developed abilities could take down a red. So why where reds weaponized instead of oranges?

Comment: How hard is it for an Orange to control an Red?

Comment: it's fairly easy from what i can tell:

Comment: " He only had to look at me, flick his gaze towards mine with that arrogant smirk. I felt the rising waves of anger distill to a perfect, piercing strike."

Comment: so it seems to me like they just have to be angry/scared enough of someone to get into their minds

Comment: You’re comparing reds and oranges!

Comment: Wasn’t the whole point that Clancy was really behind the army of Reds? Since he’s an Orange he wouldn’t want other Oranges to get in his way.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that Oranges are too dangerous to control.
Think about it; Reds have broken minds as a virtue of their power; they have nervous tics, twitches, not entirely sane. It would be easy to manipulate one.
Oranges, on the other end, are not. There’s the possibility that their minds are stronger than most, their willpower, and this is why they’re Oranges. The powers manifest around the personalities, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Some reds can stop themselves from being controlled by oranges, they're violent and aggressive but only because the government uses them, I think they are the strongest that's why government used them because they are known for what I said but can manipulate and create fire. An orange may have the mind control power, and are killed on sight for that reason; Their government knows some reds can mentally fight off the orange and reds can be unpredictable. So naturally the government would want to use those strong weapons.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to include one or more relevant quotes from the source material to corroborate what you've said here.

Comment: This isn't TikTok: no need to censor words referring to the universal fact of humans dy!ng.

Answer (score -1):

When they were first naming and finding out about peoples abilities if you think about it Reds are able to exert some measure of control over their abilities from the start whereas Oranges have to learn to control it so to the scientist doing the tests Reds would seem more powerful. 
The other reason is all of the Oranges are killed at the start of the series because they **could** be dangerous if allowed to practice and hone their abilities. Oranges at the time of the testing would be weaker than the Reds at the time of the testing. And Reds are more controllable in the end than the Oranges which led to their extermination.

Comment: Can you provide specific parts of the books or movie (or other canon material) to support this point?